# Web API get dynamic Form Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm in the process of converting an asp.net application from MVC controllers to ApiController. So far everything is going pretty smooth, except I've had a few hicccups.

The problem I'm having right now is a few methods are having requests of the form:

```
sort:FieldName
dir:DESC
filter[0][field]:FieldName
filter[0][data][type]:string
filter[0][data][value]:deadeawd
```

(the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`)

And the `sort` and the `dir` can easily be captured within a model class, and I've done so, but I don't know how to capture the `filter[0]` fields. (there could be `filter[1]` and so on as well, just how many there are is not known ahead of time, ie the data structure is dynamic).

Currently the application grabs the form data, and a method builds a query string based on the data there, but in Web API we no longer have access to the form data directly.

I could use a dynamic object, or a NameValueCollection, but I'm just trying to figure out what's the best option, what's the intended usage, and what's the best practice.

(in case you're wondering, the request data can't be changed, it's from a framework that we are using and don't have an easy way to override how it does things)

Comment: Is the structure of the Request data the same every time, or does it change?

Comment: The structure does potentially change each time. It follows that same format, but how many filters there are is subject to change. I've updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer we ended up going with was to change the framework so it sent a proper JSON object.

It was quite a bit of work, and it means it might be difficult to update it, but we're looking at moving away from the framework soon anyways, and we don't want the trivial little details of this framework to alter our API in a negative way.

If anyone is interested, the dynamic or NameValueCollection probably would've worked, and I don't think there is a best practice, because passing data like this is already bad practice.